# Performance Issues with Multithreaded code when using CallableTask/Futures and ObjectMapper

Tags: java, multithreading, jackson, future

I am working on a REST service based project in which I have two components as mentioned below-

1. Client which will make the necessary `URL's` for the Service component
2. Then Service(REST service) component will use those `URL's` to get the data from database.

In general URL will look like this-

`http://host.qa.ebay.com:8080/deservice/DEService/get/USERID=9012/PROFILE.ACCOUNT,PROFILE.ADVERTISING,PROFILE.DEMOGRAPHIC,PROFILE.FINANCIAL`

What it means from the above URL is- For the `USERID- 9012` give me the data from database for these columns-

`[PROFILE.ACCOUNT, PROFILE.ADVERTISING, PROFILE.DEMOGRAPHIC, PROFILE.FINANCIAL]`

And currently I am doing Benchmarking on the client component side. And I found out that below method is taking bunch of `time(95 Percentile)` around `~15ms`.

Below method will accept two parameters-

`List<DEKey> keys- sample data in keys will have USERID=9012`

`List<String> reqAttrNames- sample data for reqAttrNames will be-`

`[PROFILE.ACCOUNT, PROFILE.ADVERTISING, PROFILE.DEMOGRAPHIC, PROFILE.FINANCIAL]`

Below is the code-

```
public DEResponse getDEAttributes(List<DEKey> keys, List<String> reqAttrNames) {

    DEResponse response = null;
    try {
        String url = buildGetUrl(keys,reqAttrNames);

        if(url!=null){
            List<CallableTask<DEResponse>> tasks = new ArrayList<CallableTask<DEResponse>>();
            CallableTask<DEResponse> task = new DEResponseTask(url); 
            tasks.add(task);

            // STEP 2: Execute worker threads for all the generated urls
            List<LoggingFuture<DEResponse>> futures = null;
            try {
                long waitTimeout = getWaitTimeout(keys);
                futures = executor.executeAll(tasks, null, waitTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                // STEP 3: Consolidate results of the executed worker threads
                if(futures!=null && futures.size()>0){
                    LoggingFuture<DEResponse> future = futures.get(0);
                    response = future.get();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR,"Transport:getDEAttributes Request timed-out :",e1);
            }
        }else{
            //
        }
    }  catch(Throwable th) {

    }

    return response;
}
```

And the above method will give me back the `DEResponse` object.

Below is the `DEResponseTask class`

```
public class DEResponseTask  extends BaseNamedTask implements CallableTask<DEResponse> {

        private final ObjectMapper m_mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        @Override
        public DEResponse call() throws Exception {
            URL url = null;
            DEResponse DEResponse = null;
            try {
                if(buildUrl!=null){
                    url = new URL(buildUrl);

                    DEResponse = m_mapper.readValue(url, DEResponse.class);

                }else{
                    logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR, "DEResponseTask:call is null ");
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            }catch (Throwable th) {

            }finally{
            }

            return DEResponse;
        }
    }
```

Is there any problem with the way this multithreaded code is written? If yes, how can I make this efficient?

Signature for `executeAll` method for `executor` as in my company they have there own executor which will implement Sun Executor class-

```
/**
     * Executes the given tasks, returning a list of futures holding their 
     * status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever
     * happens first.  <tt>Future.isDone()</tt> is <tt>true</tt> for each
     * element of the returned list.  Upon return, tasks that have not completed
     * are cancelled.  Note that a <i>completed</i> task could have terminated
     * either normally or by throwing an exception.  The results of this method
     * are undefined if the given collection is modified while this operation is
     * in progress.  This is entirely analogous to
     * <tt>ExecutorService.invokeAll()</tt> except for a couple of important
     * differences.  First, it cancels but does not <b>interrupt</b> any 
     * unfinished tasks, unlike <tt>ExecutorService.invokeAll()</tt> which
     * cancels and interrupts unfinished tasks.  This results in a better 
     * adherence to the specified timeout value, as interrupting threads may
     * have unexpected delays depending on the nature of the tasks.  Also, all 
     * eBay-specific features apply when the tasks are submitted with this 
     * method.
     * 
     * @param tasks the collection of tasks
     * @param timeout the maximum time to wait
     * @param unit the time unit of the timeout argument
     * @return a list of futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential
     * order as produced by the iterator for the given task list.  If the 
     * operation did not time out, each task will have completed.  If it did
     * time out, some of these tasks will not have completed.
     * @throws InterruptedException if interrupted while waiting, in which case
     * unfinished tasks are cancelled
     */
    public <V> List<LoggingFuture<V>> executeAll(Collection<? extends CallableTask<V>> tasks, 
                                                 Options options, 
                                                 long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException {
        return executeAll(tasks, options, timeout, unit, false);
    }
```

**Update:-**

This component is taking time as soon as I increase the load of my program which is doing Benchmarking by increasing the threads to `20`

`newFixedThreadPool(20)`

But I believe this component works fine if I use-

`newSingleThreadExecutor`

The only reason, I can think of is, might be in the above code, there is a blocking call so that is the reason threads get blocked and that's why it is taking time?

**Updated:-**

So this line should be written like this?-

```
if(futures!=null && futures.size()>0){
                    LoggingFuture<DEResponse> future = futures.get(0);
                    //response = future.get();//replace this with below code-

                    while(!future.isDone()) {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } 

                    response = future.get();
                }
```

Comment: Is the only point of the executor to kill the task if it exceeds a certain running time?

Comment: @Perception Yeah I believe so. That's why we have Timeout over there so that we can timeout as soon as it is taking lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that should be causing a performance hit other than that you're using a complicated non-standard Executor.  I realize that you don't have any choice in the matter of which Executor you can use, but out of curiosity I'd try replacing it with a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to see if this makes any difference, and bring it up with the powers that be at your work if you notice a major improvement - at my job we discovered that the encryption library written by another division was absolute crap (80-90% of our CPU time was spent in their code) and successfully lobbied them into rewriting it.

edit:

```
public class Aggregator implements Runnable {
    private static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<DEResponse>> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private static ArrayList<DEResponse> aggregation = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void offer(Future<DEResponse> future) {
        queue.offer(future);
    }

    public static ArrayList<DEResponse> getAggregation() {
        return aggregation;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) { // make sure that all of the futures are added before this loop starts; better still, if you know how many worker threads there are then keep a count of how many futures are in your aggregator and quit this loop when aggregator.size() == [expected number of futures]
            aggregation.add(queue.poll().get());
        }
    }
}

public void getDEAttributes(List<DEKey> keys, List<String> reqAttrNames) {
    try {
        if(url!=null){
            try {
                futures = executor.executeAll(tasks, null, waitTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                if(futures!=null && futures.size()>0){
                    Aggregator.offer(futures.get(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zim-Zam for the suggestion. Yeah I will try that out for sure. I also updated my question with few more details as well. It might be you can get some more ideas. Thanks.

Comment: `future.get()` is blocking; assuming that this method is in its own thread, you can replace it with `while(!future.isDone()) {Thread.sleep(500);} future.get();` so that you don't spin-wait.

Comment: Thanks Zim Zam. Yes it will be in its own thread. I updated my question with your suggestions. Can you take a look, I made the right changes at right place?

Comment: Thanks. I missed one more word to add there. I added there again. Take a look again and let me know if it looks good. Sorry about that. But by this way what benefit I will be getting?

Comment: It looks correct. The benefit is that before the future.get() might have been spin-waiting, meaning that it would continue to consume CPU resources while waiting for the future to complete - if you have a lot of threads doing this then it can have a negative impact on performance. This way you only use the CPU in half-second intervals, and you can have as many threads sleep-waiting as you want without choking the CPU.

Comment: As we are sleeping here for 500ms in the suggestion you mentioned. So this `500ms` time will also get added up in my end to end performance right? And our expected SLA for end to end performance is around `~10ms`.

Comment: My bad, I forgot you had said that you have a runtime of 15ms. In that case, use a separate aggregation thread that had a ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future> or a synchronized ArrayList<Future>; your getDEAttributes methods put their futures on this queue. Iterate through this list until it's empty; if a future isDone then remove it from the list and call future.get on it. Meanwhile, let the getDEAttributes methods in your DEResponseTasks end so that their threads terminate. The point of all this is that you replace several spin-wait threads with only one spin-wait thread.

Comment: On second thought, just keep calling future.get() in your aggregator - this is simpler than checking future.isDone().  See my edit for an example of what I mean.  The only tricky part is making sure that the aggregator doesn't quit too early - if possible, don't start the aggregator until the worker threads have been started.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your code correctly, there is one clear performance issue. This:

```
public class DEResponseTask  extends BaseNamedTask implements CallableTask<DEResponse> {
    private final ObjectMapper m_mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

is getting called once per task, and creation of `ObjectMapper` instances is very expensive.

There are many way to fix this, but you probably want to either:

1. Make m_mapper reference static (just created once) -- mappers are safe to share once configured, OR
2. Pass in shared `ObjectMapper` (sharing is safe)

Doing this should make a big difference for JSON handling efficiency.

Comment: Yeah, how can I forgot about that. I just need to add static right? Something like this?  `private static final ObjectMapper m_mapper = new ObjectMapper();`  Right?

Comment: Yup, that is the simplest way.